# ¿Por qué no se puede declarar dos clases tipo public en un archivo java?

Tags: java

Se que la especificación así lo dicta pero no es esa mi inquietud, sino averiguar porqué.

```
public class Clase1{
}

public class Clase2{
}
```

---

O también podría ser:

```
public class Clase1{
}

public enum enum1{
}
```

---

O también podría ser:

```
public class Clase1{
}

public interface T{
}
```

El compilador dice que cada clase en un archivo nombrado de la misma forma.

Comment: Solo un tipo public??? Puedes declarar cuantos public quieras... o te refieres a la `class`?

Comment: Perdón, una clase.

Comment: No tienes por qué declararla public, puedes declarar una clase private (de hecho se puede usar para crear clases internas a las que nadie más tiene acceso), puedes no ponerle modificador... Cada caso tiene su uso, el *problema* es que si no la haces `public` nadie podrá usarla a no ser que la hayas declarado *dentro* de otra, en cuyo caso la clase solo será accesible por la clase que la tiene dentro

Comment: Más bien me gustaría averiguar porque no puede declarar dos clases public en un mismo archivo, o una lcase y una interfaz public o una clase y un enum public.

Comment: Porque en java cada archivo debe llevar el nombre de la clase pública que tiene, si tienes dos... cómo llamas al archivo?? De todas maneras, una de las máximas de Java es la *modularización*, por eso fuerza a que cada clase vaya en un archivo con su nombre.

Comment: "Porque en java debes..." no explica el porqué. Por algún motivo (que es precisamente lo que intento averiguar) no se pueden meter dos clases public, interfaces, enum etc en un archivo. Puedo meter un indeterminado número de clases no public mientras el archivo se llame como la clase public... Cuál es la lógica de la especificación?

Comment: Pues el por qué... tendrás que preguntarle a quien diseñó esa regla. El hecho es que el compilador de java (javac) hace ese check. De hecho, si quieres puedes probar a compilar una clase `test` metida en un archivo `test` y una vez compilada renombras el archivo `.class` a lo que quieras y ejecutas ese archivo con un nombre que no coincide con el de la clase que lleva dentro y verás ... ***que todo funciona!*** Es el propio compilador de java el que hace esa comprobación, y a la JVM le da un poco igual cómo se llamen las cosas

Comment: Para preguntar sobre un punto, lo que debes de hacer es agregar un código que muestre la duda que tienes, porque de la pobre forma que escribes tu pregunta mas parecido a una adivinanza para los que te contestan, porque dentro de una clase si se puede crear múltiples clases  publicas incluso un modelo completo de base de datos se podría declarar con un solo archivo, siempre y cuando no se alcance el limite máximo que puede pesar una clase java, es solo que ¿será mi respuesta lo que preguntas? no lo se, por eso nadie coloca una respuesta y solo comentan.

Comment: Perdón @RobertoEMoran. Ahí tienes el código.

Comment: @Javi ahora si ya puede contestar, llevara un poco de tiempo explicar todo pero ahí estará mi respuesta.

Comment: @TomuRain lo que comentas no es correcto. En un mismo archivo `.java` puedes tener declarados calquier cantidad de tipos de alto nivel siempre y cuando como máximo solo uno tenga el modificador de acceso `public`. Por otro lado, ni `protected` ni `private` son modificadores de acceso válidos en declaraciones de clases.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Para contestar este tipo de preguntas debes ir a la [Especificación de Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/jls8.pdf) `pagina section 7.6 top level type declaration` como podemos ver en el código de ejemplo:

```
package points;
class Point {
    int x, y; // coordinates
    PointColor color; // color of this point
    Point next; // next point with this color
    static int nPoints;
}
class PointColor {
    Point first; // first point with this color
    PointColor(int color) {
        this.color = color;
    }
    private int color; // color components
}
```

La especificación define que no hay restricción para este caso, espera si decimos que es posible agregar más de una clase publica en un archivo .java ¿Por qué falla en la prueba? si lo acabas de demostrar en tú pregunta, la repuesta simple es `porque cuando se creó el compilador de java se definió esta restricción`. Ahora para entender la razón más allá de un
`porque si`, debemos de saber que el compilador obliga que para toda `clase A` debe de existir al menos un archivo con el nombre `A` y la extensión `.java o .jav` en el paquete especificado, esto es porque cuando se realiza el proceso de `compiling-linking-loading` para hacer accesible el código compilado a las demás clases esto facilita al `Compilador de Código Java` o a una implementación de un `Compilador de Código Java por ejemplo el de OpenJDK` encontrar la clase dentro del mismo paquete.

Imaginemos el siguiente contexto:

```
package es.java;

public class A {
    private B b;
}

public class B {
}
```

En este caso tenemos una `clase A` que hace referencia a una `clase B` en el mismo archivo , cuando se realiza el proceso `compiling-linking-loading` al compilar la clase `A` hace referencia a la clase `B` que aun no está compilada, como ambas clases están en el mismo archivo y se permite más de una clase por archivo, el compilador tiene que ir a verificar todas las clases dentro del paquete `es.java` para establecer que la `clase B` a compilar es efectivamente la que está dentro del mismo archivo que la `clase A` y no dentro de otro archivo `.java` que este dentro del mismo paquete `es.java` para descartar una clase duplicada, porque recuerda que para las clases en el mismo paquete no se realiza un `import` que le especifique al compilador la ruta exacta de la clase `B` en este caso.

En conclusión: La restricción es para optimizar la velocidad de compilación y todos los demás compiladores heredaron la restricción para mantener el estándar del compilador de Oracle y que el código que compilan sea 100% compatible entre todos los compiladores, a pesar de que el estándar si lo permite.

Y para las clases anidadas, que al final son una o más clases publicas dentro de otra:

```
public class YoSoyTuPadre {
    private Hijo1 hijo1;
    private Hijo2 hijo2;

    public class Hijo1 {
        private String nombre;
    }

    public class Hijo2 {
        private String nombre;
    }
}
```

Pues, es solo visual el compilador separa la clase en diferentes clases compiladas cada una con su respectivo nombre, si compilas el código que muestro `javac YoSoyTuPadre.java` genera 3 clases `YoSoyTuPadre.class, YoSoyTuPadre$Hijo1.class y YoSoyTuPadre$Hijo2.class` colocando la referencia en el nombre para saber que se compilo de una clase anidada.

Answer (score 6):

Java fue construido desde el principio para ser completamente orientado a objetos. Todo en Java es un objeto (salvo algunas excepciones), y **todo en Java reside en una clase** (recordemos que una clase es un molde a partir del cual pueden crearse varios objetos).

**El código fuente se guarda en archivos con el mismo nombre que la clase que contienen y con extensión “.java”**. Una clase (class) declarada pública (public) debe seguir este convenio. Si tenemos una clase llamada Hola, su código fuente deberá guardarse en el fichero “Hola.java”.

El compilador genera un archivo de clase (con extensión “.class”) por cada una de las clases definidas en el archivo fuente.

Todo se encuentra en la [especificación oficial del lenguaje Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/)